# Pantech PC 5750 card giving a 633 conflict when trying to use it

Tags: wwan

I have a Verizon Pantech PC5750 WWAN card.  Been using it for about a year or two now.  EVDO RevA so nice and fast when available.

There was a VZAccess update (to 7.3.11 I think) and once I did the update, I started getting a 633 error.  I cannot find standalone drivers or firmware newer than I have, to try that kind of update.

Hard to find any good solutions using the Google.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the PC card was using COM8, and nothing else was using COM8.  Nonetheless, when I switched it to use COM11 (Randomly selected) it suddenly started working.  Very odd.  Since there was nothing else I could find on the topic I figured I would post it here.